# Access files outside public folder in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, multi-tenant, codeigniter-4

I am working on multi tenant application in CodeIgniter4 in which I have a folder on root of my domain that caters to specific tenant like http://example.com/test and http://example.com/test1
I have implemented the multitenant architecture by placing the contents of public folder in tenant specific folder (test  and test1  in my example). each tenant having its own set of files (which are usually kept under public folder).
[Screenshot of current directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUcKC.png)
I need to store some common Javascript, css and images files accessible to all the tenants.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing, but I'm further behind than you, can you tell me how you managed to get the structure working?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your public/.htaccess file to create a fallback for common files.
If a request is made for */test/app.js*, and the file does not exist, then this rule will try to serve */app.js* instead.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|txt))$
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|txt))$ /$2 [L]
```

Add this above the rewrite rule for index.php.

Comment: Thanks @jan. actually the contents of test as well as test1 are the contents of public folder, so do you meant hat I need to change/update .htaccess in each tenants folder..
Also I was thinking if I could designate some folder say 'commons' on the root and then access the files (css/js) from this folder for each tenant.